# Get HTML of multiple divs with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple divs formatted like as follows

```
<div class="slot_totals">8.00 hrs</div>
```

And I want to get the values from that and add them, but I can't get it to work for some reason. This is my code so far:

```
function refreshTotals() {
    var $totalHours = 0.00;
    for (var $i=0; $i<$('.slot_totals').length; $i++) {
        var $slotTotal = $('.slot_totals').html().split(" ");
        $slotTotal = Number($slotTotal[0]);
        $totalHours += $slotTotal;
    }
    // $('').html($totalHours.toFixed(2)+' hrs');
    console.log($totalHours.toFixed(2)+' hrs');
}
```

It does calculate fine, but it's only the first value over and over. I think it's got to do with an array but not sure how to select each item.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you call the `refreshTotals()` function? Have you included the jQuery library?

Comment: @showdev yes it's triggered from another function, and yes I have :). It calculates, but it just keeps taking the first `.slot_totals` value. I think it's got to do with looping the array but can't work out how to select it

Comment: @ochi no that's coming from the split the lounge above.

Comment: Oh I see. You'll need to specify the instance of `.slot_total` you want to add to the total. I suggest using [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) for the loop. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/x4tah7y6/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.each()` to iterate over your `.slot_totals`.
I think `parseFloat()` should be enough to parse the values.

```
$(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.slot_totals').each(function (index, slot) {
        sum += parseFloat(slot.innerHTML);
    });
    alert(sum);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kta7y5cy/

Comment: You are a legend!! I've been going nuts over this. Thanks :D

Comment: I'd be glad to! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

`$('.slot_totals').html()` will always return the html of the first element in the collection represented by the selector. This is basically true for almost all jQuery `getters` since only one value can be returned

You could use `eq()` to define the matching indexed element.

```
var $slotTotal = $('.slot_totals').eq($i).html().split(" ");
```

Reference:  [**eq() Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually select which `.slot_totals` element you're operating on in each loop. Change this line:

```
var $slotTotal = $('.slot_totals').html().split(" ");
```

to this one:

```
var $slotTotal = $('.slot_totals').eq($i).html().split(" ");
```

---

Your code could be made more expressive and more readable if you used jQuery's `.each` function instead:

```
function refreshTotals() {
    var $totalHours = 0.00;
    $('.slot_totals').each(function () {
        var $slotTotal = $(this).html().split(" ");
        $slotTotal = Number($slotTotal[0]);
        $totalHours += $slotTotal;
    });
    console.log($totalHours.toFixed(2)+' hrs');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLeve252/9/)

Updated Code:

```
function refreshTotals() {
    var $totalHours = 0.00;
    for (var $i=0; $i<$('.slot_totals').length; $i++) {
        var $slotTotal = $('.slot_totals:eq('+$i+')').html().split(" ");
        $slotTotal = Number($slotTotal[0]);
        $totalHours += $slotTotal;
    }
    // $('').html($totalHours.toFixed(2)+' hrs');
    console.log($totalHours.toFixed(2)+' hrs');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery `.each` code

```
$(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $('.slot_totals').each(function (index, value) {
        var thisSlotTotal = $(value).html().split(" ");
        thisSlotHours = Number(thisSlotTotal[0]);
        console.log(thisSlotHours.toFixed(2) + ' hrs');
        total += thisSlotHours;
    });
    alert(total);
});
```

**[DEMO: JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r8moytp7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to convert the jQuery collection to a true array with `.get()`, then use `.reduce()` to scan the array and make a running total.

Also, use `parseInt()` (or `parseFloat()`) to convert the numeric part of each string to Number.

```
function refreshTotals() {
    var total = $('.slot_totals').get().reduce(function(total, el) {
        return total + parseInt($(el).html());//or parseFloat()
    }, 0);
    console.log($totalHours.toFixed(2)+' hrs');
}
```